# How to do it recursively if function depends on only one parameter

Tags: recursion, math, arguments, min

I need to do it with recursion, but the problem is that function depends on only ONE parameter and inside function it depends on two ( k and n ), also how to find minimum value if it returns only one value?

The function is :

[image: []]

I've already tried to make random k, but I don't think that is really good idea.

```
F1(int n) {
  Random random = new Random();
  int k = random.Next(1,10);
  if (1 <= k && k <= n){
    return Math.Min(F1(k - 1) + F1(n - k) + n);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Calculating those values with pure recursion is a very bad way to do it--many values would be recalculated. Are you allowed to use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) in addition to the recursion?

Comment: As the current sole answer and your comment show, your function is not completely defined since you have not told us what `T(0)` is. That value is used twice explicitly in the formula for `T(n)` for each `n` (for `k=1` and for `k=n`), and if you use pure recursion it will be used very many times. What is `T(0)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a loop traversing all k values in range 1..n. Something like this:

```
F1(int n) {
   if (n == 0) 
      return ????  what is starting value?
   minn = F1(0) + F1(n - 1) + n
   for (int k = 2; k <= n; k++)
     minn =  Math.Min(minn, F1(k - 1) + F1(n - k) + n);
   return minn;
}
```

Comment: Math.Min function requires 2 or more arguments to compare which one is smaller...

Comment: @E.Snieckus Corrected

Comment: I have no starting value, just that function i pasted above. If i enter 1 insted yours "????" and start with n = 5 entered, then I get a message: "System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'. Any ideas?

Comment: Every recurrency must have stop condition, it should be described together with your formula for T(n)

Comment: @MBo I think the stop condition is at `n==0` since `k` can be equal to `n` in the expression `F1(n-k)`. That is why the stack overflows. It should also be `minn = F1(0) + F(n - 1) + n`.

Comment: @Gilles-Philippe Paillé Yes, it looks fine